# How to write PHP code to go through records one at a time?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

So I'm new to php/mysql.  I am testing with a very small database (single table with only 10 records) as I'm just trying to learn.

I'm displaying the following result on a php page: select * from mytable where city = "atlanta"

It works.. the result shows up on my page.  Now, I'm wondering, how can I put a link under this record that says "show next result" and on clicking it, it simply pulls up a new page with the next result in my database?

Does this require a whole pagination script or is there a simple way?

Thanks!

Comment: What do mean by `next result`?  Another city (eg. `San Diego`) or the next city returned by selected all the `atlanta`s?  If the latter, how are you pulling just a single city to begin with?  Can you post you php script and the database structure in an update?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to include an integer `$_GET` variable that is the row number + 1.

```
<a href="index.php?id=<?php echo ($id + 1) ?>" />
```

Then for your PHP script, you need to get the value, or use a default value (`0`) if one is not provided.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['id']))
        $id = 0;
    else
        $id = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Don't forget to bound your integer, so you can't get invalid results. In your case, make sure that `$id` does not go below `0` or above `9`. Something simple like

```
    if($id < 0) $id = 0;

    if($id > 9) $id = 9;
```

should work. This goes immediately after the previous code sample.

Then for your query, simply do

```
$sql = "select * from mytable where city = 'atlanta' LIMIT {$id}, 1";
```

Notice the `LIMIT` clause here that takes two parameters. The first, your current `$id` number tell the query where to start looking in the result set. The second parameter tells it how many results from the start it should take. In this case, we always want one, so we'll leave it as `1`.

Of course, you should parametrize this query, but since it sounds like you're just learning SQL, that's not a huge deal. If this was a public site, you would need to though.

You could also use `mysql_num_rows` or the PDO equivalent to get the total number of applicable rows, then determine whether `$id + 1` is greater than the total number of rows (meaning you were on the last record), and if so, not display the link to the next record.

Complete code

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['id']))
        $id = 0;
    else
        $id = $_GET['id'];

    if($id < 0) $id = 0;

    if($id > 9) $id = 9;

    $sql = "select * from mytable where city = 'atlanta' LIMIT {$id}, 1";

    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
?>

Display your result here

<?php if( ( $id + 1 ) < mysql_num_rows($result) ) :

<a href="index.php?id=<?php echo ($id + 1) ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `$id = (int) $_GET['id'];` casting integers from GEt is a good thing, especially for beginners

Comment: Good solution, however I'd strongly advise to use PDO (preferred by me) or mysqli instead of the soon to be deprecated mysql extension. It's good practice to use prepared statements -- the earlier you start, the better (beginner question).

Comment: Had to work a bit harder on making this work in my testing, but.. well worth it.  I learned a bunch from it.  Works great!  Thanks so much for the great example and the explanation!

Comment: @regilero Definitely forgot about considering float input, you're absolutely correct there. 
Glad we could help, hope your PHP learning goes much farther. As middus and I suggested, be sure to look into PDO or mysqli, since, although base mysql is great for beginners, it has massive security problems and is soon to be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Worked it out tonight!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking is paging in php.There are so many tutorials on the web.[here](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_paging.php) is one you can see

Answer (score 3):

A whole pagination script? :) Nah, just something like this

```
$items_per_page = 1;
$page = max( 1, (int) $_GET['page'] );
$offset = ($page-1) * $items_per_page;
$limit = $items_per_page;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT {$offset}, {$limit}"
```

Now just call your script using

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=1
http://localhost/index.php?page=2
http://localhost/index.php?page=3
etc
```

Comment: Wow!  You guys are good!  :)  Thanks much.  I'm going to play with all the responses now... as my goal is just learning.. and I want to understand what you've written here.  I'll holler back.
Thanks again!

Comment: This one worked like a champ!  Wow!!  Thanks so much!!  I'm going to check out the other solutions now...  but I can't believe you accomplished this is so few lines.    THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

> Now, I'm wondering, how can I put a link under this record that says "show next result" and on clicking it

You must provide your link with next data base condition key value.

For example
Your Page is:

From db selected :atlanta

Link=>Next Entry(Here you must provide the next condition. Your real condition is where city = "atlanta" so next You must know)

The right way to do this is create sql question in this example

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id='<?=$_POST['id']?>'";
```

and in this way you can print link

```
<a href='?id=<?=db["id"]+1?>'>Next Entry</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! The others got me going and this gave me the 'next link' info I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of offhand (if you don't want to use a fullblown pagination script) is to get the ids of your rows in an array (probably using `array_keys()`), track the currently active key (via $_GET) then use some simple logic to figure out what the previous and next values in the id array are, and use them in building the nav links.