# How to split search results into pages?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pagination

How to split the search results into pages? (like page 1, page 2, page 3...)

When the user searches for products on my e-commerce website, I want results to be split into several pages showing around 20 products per page. The search results are the outcome of database query.

**For example:** If the user searches for Samsung mobiles so my query will be:

`SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE BRAND='SAMSUNG';`

Suppose the above query returns 55 results, how to show them into pages (1,2 and 3)?

I am using `PHP`, `MySQL`, `Apache` on Windows machine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793105/how-to-write-php-code-to-go-through-records-one-at-a-time/6793152#6793152

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The appropriate SQL would be adding:

```
LIMIT start, amount
```

You can navigate like

```
search.php?start=20
```

and then code like:

```
LIMIT $start, $amount
```

with

```
$start = intval($_GET['start']);
```

and

```
$amount = 20;
```

That will result in max 20 records a page.

Comment: Ok. I will do it. But how can I know how many pages are there? Should I first query and count the number of rows without the `LIMIT` and divide by 20? Then after showing the number of pages, I can show results on different pages. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ... LIMIT 10,10. Next query: select found_rows()

Comment: @iSumitG: I must say I'm not a professional coder at all but what I would do is executing a query like `SELECT * FROM table` and then use `ceil(mysql_num_rows() / 20)`. As for the current page, you can use `$page = floor($start / 20) + 1` (because it would start at `0`).

Comment: I know I'm 5 years late but If somebody reached this point, RiaD is right, if you want only to use `mysql_num_rows()` for the query you shouldn't `SELECT * FROM table`, use `SELECT id FROM table` instead and you will get the result much faster especially if your table is big.

Answer (score 3):

Use SQL's `LIMIT` keyword to limit the amount of results from your query; for example:

> SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE BRAND='SAMSUNG' LIMIT 20, 40;

This would select 20 elements, starting at the 40th

Comment: That should do it, for more information try to google for 'pagination'

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
// Requested page
$requested_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;

// Get the product count
$r = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE BRAND='SAMSUNG'");
$d = mysql_fetch_row($r);
$product_count = $d[0];

$products_per_page = 20;

// 55 products => $page_count = 3
$page_count = ceil($product_count / $products_per_page);

// You can check if $requested_page is > to $page_count OR < 1,
// and redirect to the page one.

$first_product_shown = ($requested_page - 1) * $products_per_page;

// Ok, we write the page links  
echo '<p>';
for($i=1; $i<=$page_count; $i++) {
    if($i == $requested_page) {
        echo $i;
    } else {
        echo '<a href="/products/samsung/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
    }
}
echo '</p>';

// Then we retrieve the data for this requested page
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE BRAND='SAMSUNG' LIMIT $first_product_shown, $products_per_page");

while($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    var_dump($d);
}
?>
```

Hope its help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run a query to get total record count and than use query using limit

exampe:
select count(id) from table_name

This will return total record count in database

Answer (score 0):

In my php learning books, it provides a solution using a PHP class
it looks like this

```
<!-- language: php -->
<?php
error_reporting(0); // disable the annoying error report
class page_class
{
   // Properties
   var $current_page;
   var $amount_of_data;
   var $page_total;
   var $row_per_page;

   // Constructor
   function page_class($rows_per_page)
   {
      $this->row_per_page = $rows_per_page;

      $this->current_page = $_GET['page'];
      if (empty($this->current_page))
         $this->current_page = 1;
   }

   function specify_row_counts($amount)
   {
      $this->amount_of_data = $amount;
      $this->page_total= 
         ceil($amount / $this->row_per_page);
   }   

   function get_starting_record()
   {
      $starting_record = ($this->current_page - 1) * 
                     $this->row_per_page;
      return $starting_record;               
   }   

   function show_pages_link()
   {
      if ($this->page_total > 1)
      {
        print("<center><div class=\"notice\"><span class=\"note\">Halaman: ");
        for ($hal = 1; $hal <= $this->page_total; $hal++)
        {
           if ($hal == $this->current_page)
              echo "$hal | ";
           else   
              {
                 $script_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

                 echo "<a href=\"$script_name?page=$hal\">$hal</a> |\n";
              }
        }   
      }
   }   
}
?>
```

then we call it on the script that require paging

```
<!-- language: php -->
    <?php $per_page = 5;
    $page = new Page_class($per_page);
    error_reporting(0); // disable the annoying error report
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition GROUP BY group";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('error'.mysql_error());
    // paging start
    $row_counts = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $page->specify_row_counts($row_counts);
    $starting_record = $page->get_starting_record();

    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition GROUP BY group LIMIT $starting_record, $per_page";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die('error'.mysql_error());
    $number = $starting_record; //numbering
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows == 0 ) 
    {   // if no result is found
        echo "<div class=\"notice\">
    <center><span class=note>NO DATA</span></center>
    </div>";
    }
    else    {

        // while goes here ...

        }

?>
// call the page link
<?php
$page->show_pages_link();
?>
```

hope it helps, just tried it hours ago to my search script page (learning from books)

Comment: `error_reporting(0); // disable the annoying error report` xD you should read from a dif. book if that line was in there, the code is also open to SQL injection

Comment: Luckily, I only read that book to understand the concept. I haven't learned much about PHP since then, only manage to make small pages to ease my work. Thank you for your kind advice.